# automatically unselect previous selected button in UItableview in iphone

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview with multiple custom buttons.When I select one button that button should be highlighted and if I select any other button the  previous selected button should automatically unhighlight thereby highlighting the current selected button. How can I do it....?

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

 tempBtn.selected = NO;
    if (tempBtn != sender){
       tempBtn = sender;
        tempBtn.selected =YES;
       [ tempBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else{
        tempBtn = nil;
    }
}
```

I m doing this but here all the buttons which I click are changed to red not removing the prevoius selections colour (red) ..How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that if it is already red, that it is going red, but if the button is already red you want it to go to another color/clear ? as if you was selecting multiple rows ?

```
tempBtn.selected = !tempBtn.selected;
if(tempBtn.selected)
{
   tempBtn.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else
{
   tempBtn.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

EDIT: Due to slight question Change

On your button press:

```
-(void)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
  //Change Color to Red
   if([myMutableArray count] > 0
    {
      UIButton* button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
       button.setBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       [myMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    }
    [myMutableArray addObject:[sender tag]];
}
```

Comment: No what I mean is I have some many buttons in a gridview .When I select one button among them that should be red and if I select another button then the previusly selcted button should be clear color and present selected button should be red.I donno know how to get it...